# Remove unused CSS and JS

Tags: performance

I got this recommendation from google pagespeed tool, my pages works fine for desktop but for mobile it gets a score of 60.
check the report [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftop10appliances.com%2Fbest-air-fryers-without-teflon%2F).

I removed the css and js files manually from
`wp-content/cache/min/1/` directory but they keep being cached again.
The mobile version is affected by this, how can I solve it efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Google Page Speed tells you that cached files slow down your page not because cached files are slower than non-cached ones.

It's because (for example) file: https://whcl.ir/wp-content/cache/min/1/aad770152f8bd8d0197b0ef0ecc3052b.css is a combination of all your CSS files and it is the only one, so it contains all your theme, plugins and WP CSS code.

When files are not cached Page Speed checks them and it is listing every file (for example) like: 20 files * 50ms. Now when it is one cached file, Google checker tells you something like 1 file * 1200ms - and the one is faster but it's one so looks like a big website slowing file.

By the way, you have to know, that current page speed result is really good for a website based on a heavy theme like Hello Elementor so it will be hard to speed it up without changing listed theme.

With regard to jQuery - Page Speed tells me that it is loading 136ms, so maybe you have changed something or maybe Page Speed is giving different results in specific cases.